# Calculating the Area of Intersection Between a Plane and Rectangular Prism

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

If I have a plane, let's say the xy plane, and a rectangular prism that can be arbitrarily rotated/translated in 3 dimensions. Are there any cool algorithms/methods that can be used to determine the area of intersection between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to explicitly find the polygonal region of intersection `R` between the prism and the plane, triangulate `R` and sum the areas of the triangles to give the total intersection area.

The vertices of the intersecting polygon `R` can be found by performing a series of [line-plane intersection tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-plane_intersection) between the edges of the prism and the plane.

Based on the relative orientation of the plane/prism, the intersecting polygon could take a number of different configurations (i.e. it won't always be a rectangle!). Given a regular prism the intersecting region should always be convex though, allowing the [triangulation to be obtained as a simple fan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation).

Given a triangulation of `R` the total area of intersection is simply the sum of the triangle areas.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the polygonal region of intersection, you don't need to triangulate it to compute its area. There's a much simpler algorithm:

```
float area = 0.0f;
// Run through all segments
for (int i = 0; i < corners.Length; i++)
{
    // Get end points of segments
    Vector2 A = corners[i];
    Vector2 B = corners[(i+1) % corners.Length];

    // Add the signed(!) area of a quadrangle with two corners A, B 
    // and two corners with same y values on the y axis
    // 
    //   |---------A
    //   |    +   /
    //   |-------B
    // 
    //   |-------B
    //   |    -   \
    //   |---------A
    // 
    area += 0.5f * (A.x + B.x) * (B.y - A.y);  
}
```

Cf. http://alienryderflex.com/polygon_area/